# LibCurl: how do I compile the example code?

Tags: compiling, gcc, compiler

I have install libcurl by running:

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

Now, the folder locates at my 
`/usr/share/doc/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/examples$`.

Say I want to compile `ftpget.c`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

1. copy the source file to a directory where you have write permissions (so that the compiler is able to create the executable) e.g.

   ```
   mkdir ~/src && cd ~/src
   cp /usr/share/doc/libcurl4-doc/examples/ftpget.c ./
   ```
2. compile and link the file using gcc

   ```
   gcc -Wall -o ftpget ftpget.c -lcurl
   ```

This will create an executable called `ftpget` which you should be able to run from the current directory using `./ftpget`